# How does one find any Saturday/Sunday for a given month by using momentjs?

Tags: momentjs

I need to get either a Sunday or a Saturday in a specific month. For example, say I need a Saturday in May 2019 then any of the following dates will suffice (4th ,11th ,18th or 25th of May 2019).

I tried with momentjs and although it works well for Saturdays, it does not function as expected for Sundays.

What I tried:

1.`moment().year(2019).month(4).day("Saturday")` gives a moment object with a date of `Sat May 04 2019 16:26:37 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)`

2.`moment().year(2019).month(4).day("Sunday")` gives a moment object with a date of `Sun Apr 28 2019 16:29:37 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)`

3.`moment().year(2019).month(5).day("Sunday")` gives a moment object that has a date of `Sun Jun 02 2019 16:34:11 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)`

Although the 2nd date is on the correct day, it is in the month of April and not in May as specified with the `month(4)` parameter. For June however (no. 3), it works as expected again.

Can someone please help me find what I am doing wrong?

Any help and advise will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the following format. The year/month/date parts sets the date to the start of that month. Then you can use `isoWeekday()` to move the next Saturday/Sunday.

```js
moment()
  .year(2019)     // Set the desired year
  .month(7)       // Set the desired year, starts at 0
  .date(1)        // Set to the first day of this month and year
  .weekday(7)     // Now move to day iso day 7 (Sunday) or 6 for Saturday
  .toString()     // Render as string to see the correct result
```

Comment: I have realized a problem with this implementation. For example `moment().year(2018).month(6).date(1).isoWeekday(6).format('DD MMM YYYY')` will produce a date of `30 Jun 2018`. Which is wrong, because the month was specified as 6 (July).

Comment: I see. Not sure why but `weekday` instead of `isoWeekday` seems to work..

Comment: Ahh, thank you once again. I think I may have a reason why `isoWeekday` does not work. When you use `moment().year(2018).month(6).date(1)` the date is set to `1 July 2018`, which is a Sunday. When you add `isoWeekday(6)` it sets the date to the Saturday within that week. This is the day before 1 July 2018, thus the result is Saturday, 30 June 2019. Please do correct me if I'm wrong, you are obviously the maester ;)

Comment: Haha, no you're probably right. The docs aren't exactly very clear on this.